# Handling special characters in Splunk Filters

Tags: string, special-characters, splunk, splunk-query

**UPDATED**
New to splunk. I am setting up a new alert and filtering the results which i already know. Wanted to simplify the search by combining the filters around "error". Any suggestions on how to merge them?

```
index=cdapp ("ERROR" OR "WARNING") AND (host=prod-delivery* OR host=prod-microsvc*) NOT "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec" NOT GetResourceBundleTag NOT AH01630 NOT AH01276 NOT "*multimedia/images*" NOT "*/error/*" NOT "*-error-*" NOT "*_error" NOT "*error/404.jsp" NOT "/error.php" NOT "/error_page.htm"  NOT "error=webacc" NOT "*MessageType=Error*" NOT "*/warning*"  NOT "(no description)" 
| table _time,host,source,_raw
```

Comment: What is your question?  The subject line mentions special characters, but the body says you want to simplify.  Which is it?  For better performance, the contents of the `search` command should be moved before the first pipe.  Avoid leading wildcards in strings.

Comment: Hello RichG, sorry for the confusion, i edited it now and should be clear. Bascially, i want to merge all the filters around error.. I tried *error* but that didnt work.. Any clues, or should i be using regex. Thank you for the suggestion on the performance, i will make that change.

Comment: Updated the search command to show before the table command... @RichG i didnt understand what you meant by avoid leading wildcards.. what is the best way to define that?

Comment: I still don't understand the "special characters" reference.  I didn't mean for you to move the `search` command before `table` - I mean to move it before the first `|` and delete the 'search' keyword.  Avoiding leading wildcards means try not to put `*` at the beginning of a string.  Since only you know your data, it's difficult for an outsider to say how you can combine search terms.

Comment: Got it about the search. I will remove that. Thanks for clarifying that. For the special characters what i meant was all the below filters belong to a URL which contains the word "error".. The url has special characters like /-=_. so i wanted to have one filter which handles all these characters into one (regex?). WIth this atleast i can get rid of the leading wildcards. Hope i am clear now..    
"*/error/*"
"*-error-*"
"*_error"
"*error/404.jsp"
"/error.php"
"/error_page.htm"
"error=webacc"

Comment: Try this query.  `index=cdapp ("ERROR" OR "WARNING") AND (host=prod-delivery* OR host=prod-microsvc*) "error" NOT "https-jsse-nio-8443-exec" NOT GetResourceBundleTag NOT AH01630 NOT AH01276 NOT "(no description)" NOT "error=webacc" NOT "/error.php" NOT "/error_page.htm" 
| regex _raw!="([-\/]error[-\/])|(_error)|(MessageType=Error)|(multimedia/images)|(error/404.jsp)|(\/warning)"
| table _time,host,source,_raw`.

Comment: Thank you @RichG..